# How to query all direct reports using Azure AD Graph API?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I've been querying all the direct reports of a manager using:

```
var users = activeDirectoryClient.Users
    .Expand(x => x.DirectReports)
    .Where(d => d.ObjectId == objectId);

var foundUsers = users.ExecuteAsync().Result;
foreach (var foundUser in foundUsers.CurrentPage)
{
    IUser user = foundUser as User;
    int directReportsCount = user.DirectReports.CurrentPage.Count; // 19

    // ...

    Console.WriteLine(user.DirectReports.MorePagesAvailable); // false
}
```

I just discovered that these results are incomplete. I see a case where a Manager has 31 direct reports, but my code only returns 19. Moreover, `DirectReports.MorePagesAvailable` is `false`.

If I query individually for the other users not included in the direct reports collection and I expand its manager, I can see the manager is the expected one, so the right relationship exists in the Azure AD Graph.

Then, I tried to query all users with the manager I care, but the following code is invalid:

```
var users = activeDirectoryClient.Users
    .Where(d => d.Manager.ObjectId == objectId);
```

I get the following error:

> System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: key'

What is the right way to query all the direct reports of a user using *Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I see a case where a Manager has 31 direct reports, but my code only returns 19.

Based on the code, you were retrieve the direct reports from the user whose ObjectId equals `objectId`. Please ensure that the user is that manager you mentioned.

> What is the right way to query all the direct reports of a user using Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient?

It is same for Azure AD Graph to use the paging feature. Like the code above, we should check `MorePagesAvailable` property and get the next pages with `GetNextPageAsync()`.

And here is a piece of code that print the direct reports from the manager by paging the result. You can replace the `managerId` with the objectId of that manager:

```
    public void PrintDirectReports()
    {
        String managerId="";
        int pageSize=2;
        ActiveDirectoryClient client = GraphHelper.CreateGraphClient();
        int pageIndex = 1;
        var directoryRecports = client.Users[managerId].DirectReports.Take(pageSize).ExecuteAsync().Result;
        Console.WriteLine($"Page{pageIndex++}:");
        foreach (var report in directoryRecports.CurrentPage)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(report.ObjectId);
        }

        while (directoryRecports.MorePagesAvailable)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Page{pageIndex++}:");
            directoryRecports = directoryRecports.GetNextPageAsync().Result;
            foreach (var report in directoryRecports.CurrentPage)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(report.ObjectId);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `client.Users[managerId].DirectReports` is the way to go! Using `Expand()` produces a wrong request like `https://graph.windows.net/2b9a5aba-4bc6-416c-b1f4-0048fd3dffe5/users/5dc5eed0-6127-491c-89b8-e6535483e64e?$expand=directReports&api-version=1.6` and `client.Users[objectId].DirectReports` produces a correct request like `https://graph.windows.net/2b9a5aba-4bc6-416c-b1f4-0048fd3dffe5/users/5dc5eed0-6127-491c-89b8-e6535483e64e/directReports?api-version=1.6`